# Rspec + Capybara + Rack::Test — disable cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, rspec, capybara, rack

How do I turn off cookies in my feature test with `Rack::Test`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to disable cookies when using Rack::Test.  You can clear them during a test with

```
page.driver.browser.clear_cookies
```

which may provide the functionality you need.  If not, you can install middleware during your test runs and enable/disable the stripping of cookies on every request.  You can see an example of that at https://makandracards.com/makandra/15187-how-to-disable-cookies-in-cucumber-tests.  The example is for cucumber but should be easy enough to convert to just plain RSpec.

Comment: `page.browser.clear_cookies` returns `undefined method 'browser' for #<Capybara::Session>`. You probably meant `Capybara.current_session.driver.browser.clear_cookies`

Comment: @ViktorDanilov Yep - I missed the `driver` sorry - updated -  `page` is the same as `Capybara.current_session` if you have Capybara::DSL included